# Angular 2 routing with custom secure directive

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I found a very neat solution on another [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041192/angular2-how-to-hideno-render-the-link-in-the-menu-after-check-access?newreg=e0696738e96347cd81163ccd519f1025) post by Thierry Templier, however it is out dated for Angular 2 RC5 new router.

Basically this is the secure directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[secured]'
})
export class SecuredDirective implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('hidden') hideRouterLink: boolean = false;

  @Input() routerLink: string;

  constructor(private router: Router ) {
    console.log(router);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.routerLink);

    // How to get routeData here??
    // Auth logic
    this.hideRouterLink = true;

  }
}
```

Previously on angular's old router we could do this:

```
var instruction = this.router.generate(this.routeParams);
var data = instruction.component.routeData.data;
```

Now with RC5, I can't figure out a way how to get the router instruction.
Is there another way to do this?

**Edit: more info**

What I am trying to achieve is to grab the route data defined in the routing.ts example:

```
{ path: 'control-panel', component: ControlPanelComponent, data: { 'resources': 'controlpanel', 'privileges': 'admin'} }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below,

```
@Directive({
 selector: '[secured]'
})
export class SecuredDirective implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {
  _hideRouterLink: string = '';
  @HostBinding('style.display') get hideRouterLink() {
    return this._hideRouterLink; 
  } 
  set hideRouterLink(val: boolean){
    this._hideRouterLink =  val;
  }

  @Input('routerLink') routeParams:  any[];

  constructor(private router: Router ) {
   console.log(router);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){  
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.routeParams);
 
    // Auth Logic
    this.hideRouterLink = 'none';
  }
}
```

Here is the [Plunker!](http://plnkr.co/edit/e8VYH9on9UUQpNCaz4LG?p=preview)

Comment: How do I retrieve the RouteData though? Your solution is similar to mine. I need a way to retrieve the RouteData defined in the routes, I updated my question for more info. Thanks

Comment: @12seconds, you may get data from this.router.config, issue is if the route is lazily loaded you wont find that, I am also looking for some solution for this, If I find something will update the answer.